# Automate the synchronization process between SVN and Git

Tags: git, svn

I have migrated my SVN based projects into Git repositories but currently developers are still committing to SVN until final production move. Now I want to create some kind of job/script which can be scheduled to run daily (until final migration happens) to synchronize svn and git. And this is only for trunk where all developers commit their code on a daily basis.

I am aware that we can use following commands to manually sync one time. I am using Git Svn method.

```
    git svn rebase
    git push origin --all
```

I went through several tutorials on internet but didn't get what I want.

[update]
Based on more research, I was able to create a cron job to automate this process.

Comment: If you know the commands what is the problem then?

Comment: I can use these commands when I have already cloned ( in my local system and pushed to Github) and .git directory was created and then I can go to this path in Git bash and execute "git svn rebase". But here the ask is to automate the process where I can provide svn path and git repo path and can sync itself when script is executed.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do `git svn fetch` into a repo that wasn't cloned from SVN. Perhaps you have to start with a new repo cloned with `git svn clone` and then regularly update it with `git svn rebase`.